# Most efficient way to move row/column in 2D std::vector

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, vector, multidimensional-array

I'm creating game application in C++. I have map represented as 2-dimensional `std::vector` of `Tile` objects.

I need to update that map as player moves. From server application I get row or column with a new part of global map, which should be placed in local client's map, for example:

[image]

In a figure 1 there's a local map before player moves. Top row is filled with objects 1, center with 2 and bottom with 0. Now when player moves up, I get new top row filled with objects 3 and all the others should go down, and the previous bottom row should disappear.

I can do it just by moving required objects in `for` loops, but I was thinking if there's already some kind of algorithm in standard library or prefered by many, efficient way to achieve this kind of modifications.

EDIT:

Sorry I didn't realize that there would a difference between doing this operation for row and for column, but indeed there is. So I also editted my title, because I sometimes need to do it for column too.

Comment: So you have an `std::vector<std::vector<Tile>>`? Which dimension represents your columns, which one the rows? This is important, because it is simple to realize this "up"-command if the second dimension represents the rows. You could swap row 1 and 2, then you swap rows 1 and 3 and then you replace row 1. Swaping can be implemented efficiently by tripple XORing the vector's pointers which results in 3 processor instructions per swap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to implement an iterator and don't move the elements of the vectors at all. Simply define a variable for the index of the top row (on the screen), then use the modulo operator to iterate over all the rows (so only the 000 row should be overwritten with 333, and the top row index will be 2 instead of 0). This algorithm is effecient (only as many memory writes as needed), and could be used to scroll in any direction:

- Moving upwards: decrement the top row index (mod row number), change the last row
- Moving downwards: increment the top row index (mod row number), change the first row
- Moving left: decrement the left col index (mod col number), change the last col
- Moving right: increment the left col index (mod col number), change the first col.

Comment: It sounds as a really good solution for me, but I have one, probably silly question - you write that I should implement an iterator, but implement it where?

Comment: @dziwna: Just wrap your matrix in a class that also holds your row/column indexes, and provide accessors that take those indexes into account (as well as scrolling methods, while you're at it).

Answer (score 3):

There are two standard containers that immediately come to mind when you need fast insertion/erase at *both* extremities: `std::deque` and `std::list`. However they have their particular requirements and limitations.

If you are stuck with a vector, you can either leverage C++11 move semantics which will allow you to efficiently move the objects instead of copying them, or as @WebMonster mentioned you could use some sort of circular index into your buffer which completely eliminates the need for moving/copying.

Given your requirements, and assuming they are complete, I'd probably go for @WebMonster's solution which is the most efficient. **Edit:** now that your requirements have changed and that you also need to scroll on columns, his solution "circular index" is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can use std::swap that is specialized for vectors and is efficient, because it requires only several pointer swaps for two vectors. Also, you can make use of std::rotate, but I'm not sure if it uses swapping technique.

Unfortunately, this will work only if you have a vector of rows and you need to shift rows, or you have a vector of columns and you need to shift columns.
It seems that to do both operations efficiently, you have to use some more complicated data structure.

Answer (score 2):

I would give [boost matrix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm) a try.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way would be to use:

`std::std::swap_ranges()` for moving the already existing rows in your 2D `std::vector`

and

`std::transform()` for modifying the row that needs to be replaced with new values.